# Reminders & iCloud sync

Tags: icloud, reminders

I am using iCloud and Reminders and since a couple of weeks I am seeing a strange behaviour:

- new events are correctly added to all the devices
- events marked as "done" are not marked on other devices (none of them)

I am using several Yosemite and iOS devices. Both behaviours are the same independently from the device.

**Update**

The events are marked as "done" in iCloud (checked with a browser), this means that synchronising from a device (iOS or OS X) to iCloud works. In the other direction, i.e., from iCloud to devices it does not.

Comment: I can't reproduce de problem on OS X 10.10.3 / iOS 8.3; are those standard reminders? Do they repeat, have alarms, geofences?

Comment: Both standard and repeating. All with an alarm.

Comment: Tried to reproduce with alarm, and creating reminder from OS X / iOS; it works fine here, sorry.